# How to access key, value in json / ruby

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a json file like this, and I try to display the different value in my html:

```
{
    "testimonials": [
        {
            "office": "Test",
            "authors": "Benjamin",
        },
        {
            "office": "consultant",
            "authors": "Maxime ",
        },
        {
            "office": "DAF",
            "authors": "Alexandre",

        },
        {
            "office": "CEO",
            "authors": "Raphaël",
          },
        {
            "office": "Consultant",
            "authors": "Alexis",
        },
        {
            "office": "CEO,",
            "authors": "Sylvain",
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone help me, for example, to access to display the value 'Alexis'

Comment: Parse to Hash: take a look at the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html, if not clear please, post back.

Comment: I checked but I don't get it, do I necessarily need to parse it ?

Comment: If your question is "Is the documentation true?", then the answer is: Yes.

Comment: "...access to display the value 'Alexis'" suggests you know `'Alexis'` is the value of some key of some nested hash of some nested array. If so, `puts 'Alexis'` is all you need. If you don't know if there is such a value do you wish to return `true` or `false`, depending on whether if `h[:testimonials][i][:authors] == 'Alexis'"` for some `i`, implying you are aware of the structure of the hash?...

Comment: ...Or perhaps rather than returning `true` or `false` you wish to return  `g ={ "office": "Consultant", "authors": "Alexis"`, so that, for example, you could compute `g[:office] #=> "Consultant"`, that corresponds with `:authors` having a value `"Alexis"`. This is an example of trying to state a question unambiguously in terms of an example. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Here are two small ways to improve the examples you use in questions. 1) make the example as small as possible without simplifying away the essesence of the problem. Here the array that is the value of `:testimonials` has six elements. It would be equally effective if it had just two element, the hash for which the value of `:authors` is `"Alexis"` and one other hash. 2) Assign a variable to all of the example's given values (e.g, `h = {
    "testimonials": [....] }`). That way readers can refer those variables (`h`) in answers and comments without having to define them (or here, it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JSON due to the trailing commas within your hashes. If you fix the commas, minify the JSON to make it easier to work with, and save it as a string, then you can begin to work with it in Ruby:

```
json = '{"testimonials":[{"office":"Test","authors":"Benjamin"},{"office":"consultant","authors":"Maxime "},{"office":"DAF","authors":"Alexandre"},{"office":"CEO","authors":"Raphaël"},{"office":"Consultant","authors":"Alexis"},{"office":"CEO,","authors":"Sylvain"}]}'
```

Now parse it into a real Ruby object:

```
hash = JSON.parse(json)
=> {
    "testimonials" => [
        [0] {
             "office" => "Test",
            "authors" => "Benjamin"
        },
        [1] {
             "office" => "consultant",
            "authors" => "Maxime "
        },
        [2] {
             "office" => "DAF",
            "authors" => "Alexandre"
        },
        [3] {
             "office" => "CEO",
            "authors" => "Raphaël"
        },
        [4] {
             "office" => "Consultant",
            "authors" => "Alexis"
        },
        [5] {
             "office" => "CEO,",
            "authors" => "Sylvain"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a hash that has an array of hashes inside it. You should access it using the standard methods for [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) and [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html).

Start by getting the value of the only key in the hash, which is an array:

```
array = hash['testimonials']
=> [
    [0] {
         "office" => "Test",
        "authors" => "Benjamin"
    },
    [1] {
         "office" => "consultant",
        "authors" => "Maxime "
    },
    [2] {
         "office" => "DAF",
        "authors" => "Alexandre"
    },
    [3] {
         "office" => "CEO",
        "authors" => "Raphaël"
    },
    [4] {
         "office" => "Consultant",
        "authors" => "Alexis"
    },
    [5] {
         "office" => "CEO,",
        "authors" => "Sylvain"
    }
]
```

You indicated you wanted to fetch a value from index 4:

```
sub_hash = array[4]
=> {
     "office" => "Consultant",
    "authors" => "Alexis"
}
```

And that you wanted to return the string `Alexis`:

```
string = sub_hash['authors']
=> "Alexis"
```

Or put it all together in one line:

```
string = hash['testimonials'][4]['authors']
=> "Alexis"
```

Or one even shorter line:

```
JSON.parse(json)['testimonials'][4]['authors']
=> "Alexis"
```

Comment: Or `hash.dig('testimonials', 4, 'authors')` which will also take care of `nil` errors due to missing elements.

Comment: Yep, what @Stefan said. (but I had a feeling we were starting from a fairly remedial place and wanted to avoid the more clever methods, plus the ruby-on-rails-3 tag makes me assume we're probably not using ~> Ruby 2.3)

Comment: Good catch, I didn't see the ruby-on-rails-3 tag

Comment: Thanks for your time and your explanation ! I have an error 785: unexpected token at '{:testimonials=>[{:office=>"Test", :authors=>"Benjamin"}, {:office=>"consultant", :authors=>"Maxime "}, {:office=>"DAF", :authors=>"Alexandre"}, {:office=>"CEO", :authors=>"Raphaël"}, {:office=>"Consultant", :authors=>"Alexis"}, {:office=>"CEO,", :authors=>"Sylvain"}]}' while I parse it, do you where it comes from ? (I do a .to_s on my json file because I can't add string manually)